# converting data frame to matrix, sapply is returning a list

Tags: r, matrix, sapply

I want to crate matrix where by the result shows the difference between columns. I have used spapply which visually returns the correct results but as list. I have a one row DF. That is all numeric.
Example data:

```
|A| B|  C|
|12|6|  7|
```

I want to return

```
    A|  B|  C|
A|  0|  6|  5|
B|  6|  0|  1|
C|  5|  1|  0|
```

I have tried

```
 mymatrix<-sapply(DF, function(x) abs(x - DF))
```

This returns a list that looks like matrix and gives correct information. I need it as matrix not a list.

Comment: Have you tried `as.matrix(mymatrix)`?

Comment: You can use `as.matrix(mymatrix)` or if you have only 1 row use it as vector `mymatrix<-sapply(unlist(DF), function(x) abs(x - unlist(DF)))`

Comment: @jimRayer, Yes it failed.

Comment: @Bantanicheck mymatrix<-sapply(unlist(DF), function(x) abs(x - unlist(DF))) worked!